# Better way to write generic comparator of container

Tags: java, generics

I've got an container object like this:

```
class Container<V> {
    V value;
}
```

and want to write a `Comparator` for it which should compare the `value` only if it's comparable.

The best I could come up with is this:

```
class ValueComparator<V extends Comparable<V>, C extends Container<V>>
implements Comparator<C> {

    @Override
    public int compare( C o1, C o2 ) {
        return o1.value.compareTo( o2.value );
    }

}
```

which can be used in this way:

```
    Container<String> x1, x2;

    new ValueComparator<String,Container<String>>().compare( x1, x2 );
                        ^^^^^^ ?
```

The question is: Is there a better way to implement this in order to get rid of the redundant type information so that I could write:

```
    new ValueComparator<Container<String>>().compare( x1, x2 );
```

Comment: What would you want the behaviour to be if V isn't Comparable?

Answer (score 3):

You can change your `ValueComparator` declaration like this:

```
class ContainerComparator<V extends Comparable<V>> implements Comparator<Container<V>> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Container<V> o1, Container<V> o2 ) {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Now you can declare it with a single type parameter:

```
new ContainerComparator<String>().compare(x1, x2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is the wrong direction. (Basically Container<V> is the base class for other classes and in the real code I want to use something readable like ContainerComparator<Person> instead of ContainerComparator<Integer>)